# How to change Tor port in Kali

Tags: tor

i would like to change default tor port from 9050 to 9150.
Editing /etc/tor/torsocks5.conf i can see these:

TorPort 9050

so, changing to 9150, it should work, right? it doesnt.

```
> sudo vi /etc/tor/torsocks.conf

> sudo cat /etc/tor/torsocks.conf  | grep 9150

TorPort 9150

> sudo service tor reload
> sudo service tor restart 
> sudo service tor status
● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: active (exited) since Mon 2022-06-27 13:46:11 CEST; 7s ago
Process: 43748 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 43748 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    CPU: 2ms

Jun 27 13:46:11 kali systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Jun 27 13:46:11 kali systemd[1]: Finished Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
> sudo netstat -tanp | grep tor
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      43758/tor           
tcp        0      0 192.168.85.139:36538    178.238.236.41:1337     ESTABLISHED 43758/tor           
tcp        0      0 192.168.85.139:57824    162.55.131.67:9100      ESTABLISHED 43758/tor
```

What do i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you want to change is:

```
SocksPort 0.0.0.0:9150
```

Usually this is located in `torrc` file.